# Exclude a page from _layout

Tags: svelte

Hello I am new to Svelte, Sapper & Express.

The problem:
I am using Sappers _layout.html to display 2 components (header & menu) that should be displayed on all pages, save for the login page.

What is the right way to achieve this ?

Possible solutions:
A) Serve the login page from the static folder, and use the express middleware to route to it?

B) Have the login as the root of my project and move all other routes down a level so they can share a common layout that dosnt involve the login page?

C) Put and if statement in the layout and determine when the user is on the login page to hide the header & menu components.

D) Not use the layout to display the components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preferred solution to this problem is option C — using `child.segment` to control which layout is used:

```html
<!-- src/routes/_layout.html -->
{#if child.segment === 'login'}
  <svelte:component this={child.component} {...child.props}/>
{:else}
  <div class="fancy-layout">
    <svelte:component this={child.component} {...child.props}/>
  </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Where does the child.segment come from? I see it is exported in https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/_layout.svelte but I don't know where to set it's value. Thanks

Comment: @lsabi The `segment` prop is set magically by Sapper when you navigate thru the routes. See [Sapper docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Nested_routes).

Comment: Since this answer is from 2018, this should probably be updated: `child.segment` is only `segment` now, as @mustofa.id pointed out. And the whole `<svelte:component>` line is now `<slot/>`

Comment: Can you post new answer for svelte-kit, this OP solution doesn't work.

Comment: I get `segment` is not defined in svelte-kit

Comment: @chovy SvelteKit is different from Sapper, see [migration guides](https://kit.svelte.dev/migrating). In Kit you can use `page` store to get `segment` trickily via `url.pathname`. But if you need conditionally render element/component based on user login, I suggest to use `session` store instead.

Answer (score 9):

Just adding a similar answer as the accepted one, but with updated syntax for SvelteKit as of early 2022 (still in beta).

```
<!-- src/routes/__layout.svelte -->

<script>
import { page } from '$app/stores'
</script>

{#if $page.url.pathname === '/fancy'}
  <div class="fancy-layout">
    <slot />
  </div>
{:else}
  <slot />
{/if}
```

Also, just so you know, SvelteKit is awesome. You made the right choice.