# How to leave parent layout in Sapper?

Tags: javascript, layout, parent, sapper, svelte-3

Currently, I'm working on a project which shares a `Menu` component across all pages except two pages. I added the menu component inside root `_layout.svelte` file. Now since two pages that don't need `Menu` component are nested routes. The `Menu` is appearing inside them since they are child routes. They are made to look this way. But I think there should be some way to opt-out / leave the parent layout. Otherwise I would have to remove the `_layout.svelte` root file and add `Menu` component to each route which is too much against DRY. Is there a way to leave parent `_layout.svelte` in Sapper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a page from \_layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495018/exclude-a-page-from-layout)

Answer (score 5):

using `child.segment` to control which layout is used:

> ```
> <!-- src/routes/_layout.html -->
> {#if child.segment === 'login'}
>   <svelte:component this={child.component} {...child.props}/>
> {:else}
>   <div class="fancy-layout">
>     <svelte:component this={child.component} {...child.props}/>
>   </div>
> {/if}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the solution provided to work. Can anyone provide an working example or show the solution in a bigger context?

I did solve the same problem with an if statement checking the route path.

```
<!-- src/routes/_layout.svelte-->

<script>
  import { stores } from '@sapper/app'
  { page } = stores()
</script>

{#if $page.path != "/login"} <!-- If your route file is /src/routes/login.svelte -->
  <Nav {segment}/>
{/if}

<main>
  <slot></slot>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sapper has evolved into SvelteKit 1.0, which supports this functionality inbuilt using [Advanced Routing](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing).

For e.g. using `(group)`s you can isolate pages into specific parent layouts:

```bash
src/routes/
│ (app)/
│ ├ +page.svelte
│ └ +layout.svelte
│ (marketing)/
│ ├ +page.svelte
│ └ +layout.svelte
├ admin/
└ +layout.svelte
```

In the above example:

- `(app)` and `(marketing)` are two groups used.
- `/+layout.svelte` is the root layout applied to all child routes, irrespective of which group they belong
- `/(app)/+page.svelte` will be applied with `/(app)/+layout.svelte` and `/+layout.svelte` layouts.
- `/(marketing)/+page.svelte` will be applied with `/(marketing)/+layout.svelte` and `/+layout.svelte` layouts.

*You can also granularly exclude parent layout in a nested page, using `+layout@` or `+page@` syntax. Details here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-layout*

---

Please follow the docs for more details: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts

Comment: SvelteKit and Sapper are two separate projects. SvelteKit is stable at 1.x and Sapper's development is almost discontinued except for minor fixes.